# How can I pass a parameter from the xaml markup file to the UserControl constructor?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a StepsWnd window in which UserControl StepProp is used twice, declared in a separate file.

```
 <Window x:Class="MyProject.StepsWnd"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:c1="http://schemas.componentone.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
    Height="550" Width="850">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:StepProp Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding Path=PrevStepVM}" x:Name="m_PrevStep"/>
        <local:StepProp Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding Path=CurStepVM}" x:Name="m_CurStep"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When the StepsWnd window is created, the StepProp constructor is called twice - for m_PrevStep and for m_CurStep.

```
public class StepProp : UserControl
{
    public StepProp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //...
}
```

How can I pass a parameter to the StepProp class constructor from the markup of the StepsWnd window, so that I can identify who is calling the constructor, m_PrevStep or m_CurStep? To get something like this?

```
public class StepProp : UserControl
{
    public StepProp(object parameter)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if ((string)parameter == "PrevStep")
        {
            //todo somthing
        }
        else if ((string)Param == "CurStep")
        {
            //todo somthing else
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Define a dependency property in StepProp, set it in StepsWnd, do your customisation on this property change handler.

Comment: When you create an element as a tag in XAML, only the parameterless constructor can be called. swiszcz's suggestion is the conventional way of "parameterizing" a user control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I pass a parameter to the StepProp class constructor from the markup of the StepsWnd window, so that I can identify who is calling the constructor, m_PrevStep or m_CurStep?

You can't. XAML is a *markup* language and you cannot create an instance of a `UserControl` using any other constructor than the default one that doesn't accept any arguments. So forget about using dependency injection in XAML.

If you want the constructor to behave differently depending on which instance you are creating, you should probably consider creating two different `UserControl` types that for example may share the same base class or inheriting from one another.

Alternatively you could define and set a property as suggested in the comments:

```
<local:StepProp x:Name="m_PrevStep" YourProperty="m_PrevStep" />
```

...and handle any logic in the setter or the property (or the callback if you are defining a dependency propery).

Note that the property value won't be available in the constructor though as the instance must be created before the XAML processer can actually set the property.